# If Cell A in Column A is equal to any Cell in Column B, Input the number "5"

Tags: google-sheets

I have a list of emails on two separate sheets, I want to a formula that will allow me to able to automatically input the number "5" in a column where a match was found.

If Cell A in column A is = to a value in column B then input the number 5 in column C on the same row as Cell A

What I want is essentially the same thing as a VLookup only instead of returning a value from another cell I just want when it finds a match to input the number 5

Comment: Excel and google sheets are two different applications with different codes; please clarify your tags to which one you are using.

Comment: Doesn't make sense what you are trying to do.

Comment: use COUNTIF to check in the value in cell A exists in any cell from column B. Combine it with an IF to choose to return a 5 or nothing

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I guess I should have been more specific, I am using google sheets not excel, what I want is essentially the same thing as a VLookup only instead of returning a value from another cell I just want when it finds a match to input the number 5 –

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(COUNTIF(B:B; A:A)>0; 5; ))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the comment it didnt work unfortunately, I guess I should have been more specific, I am using google sheets not excel, what I want is essentially the same thing as a VLookup only instead of returning a value from another cell I just want when it finds a match to input the number 5

Comment: @HassanAlokaily can you share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output?